# TcpClient missing data

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to write network part for my game in C# using `System.Net.Sockets` and `TcpClient` class.

- Each update server is sending information to client.
- All information is built into 2kb packets, so in 1 update 1-2-3-5-10 packets can be sent.
- Client is checking information and if  information has right format - then reading it.
- Everything is working fine, until server starts trying to send too many packets.
- When it happens client time to time is receiving packets with wrong data 1 of 20-50 packets usually.
- For example, 1-2 packets for 1 update usually are received fine, 3-10 packets for update giving wrong data streams.
- If I am starting several clients in 1 time, that should get same data streams from server - they get different numbers of success and fail data streams.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I evade this wrong data streams?

Am I just sending too much data in 1 ms and it is needed to send it over time?

This is the sending information:

```
TcpClient client;

public void SendData(byte[] b)
    {
        //Try to send the data.  If an exception is thrown, disconnect the client
        try
        {
            lock (client.GetStream())
            {
                client.GetStream().BeginWrite(b, 0, b.Length, null, null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the receiving information:

```
byte[] readBuffer;
int byfferSize = 2048;

private void StartListening()
    {
        client.GetStream().BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, bufferSize, StreamReceived, null);
    }

    private void StreamReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        try
        {
            lock (client.GetStream())
            {
                bytesRead = client.GetStream().EndRead(ar); // просмотр длины сообщения
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

        //An error happened that created bad data
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            Disconnect();
            return;
        }

        //Create the byte array with the number of bytes read
        byte[] data = new byte[bytesRead];

        //Populate the array
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            data[i] = readBuffer[i];

        //Listen for new data
        StartListening();

        //Call all delegates
        if (DataReceived != null)
            DataReceived(this, data);
    }
```

It is main network code.

Comment: Why are you using: lock (client.GetStream()) ???

Comment: Something that looks wrong (dunno of it would cause your issue, but I suspect it might) is the call to BeginWrite. That's an ASYNC (non-blocking) call, so the lock is released before the write is done, possibly leading to concurrency issues. Try replacing it with a normal Write() call.

Comment: Also, use Buffer.BlockCopy instead of a for loop to get bytes from readbuffer into data

Comment: Daniel, being honest i took realization of this from videos of one guy on youtube. Anyway as i got it, locking streams is needed cause
client.GetStream().BeginWrite and client.GetStream().BeginWrite are async operations, so it is used to be sure that stream will be unchanged during writing or reading... (i'm beginner coder, so proly i'm saying and doing something nosense)

Comment: Xcelled, i tryed use Write(), but number of bad data streams only increased. 

About Buffer.BlockCopy... mm, didnt understand, what i must do? can u give me exapmle of using this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you do with the data after you've received it, but it's quite possible that you're not reading all of the data from the connection. You have:

```
bytesRead = client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
```

There's no guarantee that the number of bytes you've read are all of the bytes that the server sent. For example, the server could have sent 2,048 bytes, but when you called `Read`, there were only 1,024 bytes available. The rest of them are still "in transit." As the [documentation for NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) says:

> The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter

You could be getting partial packets. If your `DataReceived` handlers assume that the `data` buffer contains a complete packet, then you're going to have problems.

To reliably read from a network stream, you need to know how much data you're supposed to read, or you need a record separator. Something has to make sure that if you're expecting a complete packet that you *get* a complete packet before you try to process it. Your code just checks to see if `bytesRead` is not 0. If it's anything else, you just pass it on. This is going to be a problem unless your `DataReceived` handlers know how to buffer partial packets.

On another note, you really don't need to lock the network stream. Unless you can have several threads reading from the same stream. And that would be disastrous. Ditch the lock. You don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, Jim, made quick look of recieving data, looks like it is rly cuting and  mixing streams time to time, so suppose it is the problem. Will try to improve recieving data tomorrow. 
Cant vote u up, as far dont have enough reputation :-(